# Apt-dater: Keep specific packages from updating

Tags: ubuntu, apt, automation, package-management, update

I am using [Apt-dater](http://www.ibh.de/apt-dater/) to manage updating of Ubuntu servers.

I have some packages that cannot be updated but want to still update everything else on those servers. I wonder if Apt-dater supports this. Man page and Apt-daters web site have very little documentation about using it.

So does Apt-dater have ability to do what I want?

(I could manually select and update all but problematic packages on Apt-dater but that would defeat the purpose of the software.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Pinning](http://jaqque.sbih.org/kplug/apt-pinning.html) is the canonical way to pin packages to a certain version on Debian based Linuxes.

Configuration management tools like Puppet or Chef can be used to roll out a pinning config to many hosts.

Comment: Thanks but I'd still like to know if Apt-dater can do it.

Comment: AFAIK `apt-dater` just calls `APT` on the target host and relies on a sound config there. That suggests that a pinning config should be put on the hosts that need one.